# How to find the date and time the order was cancelled in Magento 1.9.x

Tags: magento, xslt, export-to-excel, orders

Bit of a complex question for you..

I am exporting orders from Magento 1.9.4.0 using an extention from XTENTO.

It uses XSL to build 'profiles' to all me to cycle through orders programatically and export them in a format of my choice.

I have everything working aside from pulling the correct date the order was cancelled. I can see that in Magento this date appears to be in the table 'sales_flat_order_status_history'.

Looking at the table i can see the following:

[sales_flat_order_status_history table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTP6r.jpg)

And the XSL I have been using is below..

[XSL query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPu7s.jpg)

It IS finding a date; but it is finding the LAST update to the order and pulling the created_at value.

Does anyone know how I could find the FIRST timestamp where the order was in a cancelled state using the XSL notation?

The documentation for the XSL engine is available here, if helpful: https://support.xtento.com/wiki/Magento_Extensions:Magento_Order_Export_Module#2.29_Export_Fields

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be hardcoded on your module files.
You could be able to change the query it is making to the database. I can't give complete guidance since I do not have the module files to look at.

Try opening the module folder in some code editor and search for something like:

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order_status_history')
```

You will then find where the code may reside and then change the query to filter for what you want.